# Javascript array_count_values function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using an `array_count_values` function since I have translated the code from php to javascript and javascript does not have this function, but not sure on the performance of it. I'm sure it can be faster. It currently takes 50ms for 32000 iterations each time it is called.

I have one that returns a simple array:

```
function array_count_values(arr) {//returns array
    let a = [], prev;
    arr.sort();
    for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
            a.push(1)
        } else {
            a[a.length-1]++;
        }
        prev = arr[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

And another that returns an object:

```
function array_cnt_values(arr) {//returns object
    let a = [], prev;
    arr.sort();
    for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
            a[arr[i]] = 1
        } else {
            a[arr[i]]++;
        }
        prev = arr[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: What do you need it to return? What's the problem description that this code solves?

Comment: The function of the code does not need to change, they do what is needed. My question is how to improve the performance of these two pieces of code.

Answer (score 1):

Your first function just gives an array of counts, without anyway to tell what each of them are counting.

Your second function is better, as the index shows what's being counted. You can use the index to see if it already exists, which means you don't have to sort your array.

```
if( a[arr[i]] )
```

This works fine if all values are positive integers. But what if you had strings? It would still work, but you couldn't loop through the result easily. You might also run into problems if you have values equal to existing array properties like `length`.

Instead you can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which is similar to the associative array in php.

```
function array_count_values(arr) {
    let a = new Map();
    for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if ( a.has(arr[i]) ) {
            a.set(arr[i], a.get(arr[i])+1)
        } else {
            a.set(arr[i], 1)
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Yes I need both of the functions, they serve purposes for different things. But I need to optimise the performance of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'll talk about the second implementation first.

---

The name isn't well chosen. I'm aware it's supposed to mirror the PHP name, but in JavaScript it is convention to use camelCase names and not snake_case. I'd choose `countArrayValues`.

Also don't use unnecessary short and undescriptive variable names. In your case `arr` and `a` are easily confused. Better names would be, for example, `input` and `result`.

---

You are initializing `a` as an empty array. Unlike PHP in JavaScript arrays and objects are two different things (although an array is also an object, which is why is still works). An empty object in JavaScript is denoted with `{}`.

---

It's bad form to have a function like this to mutate its input. A user may not expect that their array is suddenly sorted.

Additionally it's not even needed to sort the array in this case, so leaving it out will speed it up considerably. Instead of comparing with the "previous" value, just check if the value is already in the result.

```
function countArrayValues(input) {//returns object
    let result = {};
    for ( let i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ) {
        // result[input[i]] will either result in `undefined` which is 
        // interpreted as `false`, or as the current count, which as 
        // a positive integer will be considered `true`
        if ( result[input[i]] ) {
            result[input[i]]++;
        } else {
            result[input[i]] = 1
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

Regarding the first implemention: I'm not quite sure about the use case, because just a array of numbers without any reference to the original values seems a bit pointless to me. If it's needed I'd base it's implementation on the result of the second version.

Comment: Thanks for your tips about naming conventions, it's a personal project so I just named it whatever I preferred but incidentally all my other functions are named with camel case. The point of the other count value function is to return an array which can be easily sorted. The other use is for an object with specific key names that does not need to be sorted. Hence the two separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

### Depends of the data

The best solution to the problem will depend on the data you are processing. As you have given no indication as to what the data contains I can but guess.

### Small range

If the values are a small set within a known range then the optimal solutions is to create an array that will fit all the values before the loop, fill it with zero and then count each index.

#### Example A

`values` is array of integers in the range of 0-`setSize`

```
function countValuesA(values, setSize) { // example A
    const counts = new Array(setSize);
    counts.fill(0);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { counts[values[i]]++ }
    return counts;
}
```

### Limited

This only works for values that are integers >= 0. The following solutions will work for any type of values. But as you can see in the benchmarking the above method can provide a huge advantage, So much so that is worth upstream modification to bring small range sets into an integer range.

### Unknown set with small range

If the set of values is unknown but small then you know that each iteration is more likely to find an existing value to count. Thus you can write the function to favor that situation.

When using a Map, either as `count = new Map`, or `counts = {}` there is a cost each time you access a key. This is the cost of converting the key to a hash.

So avoiding the hash calculation when possible gives an advantage.

#### Example B

When the set of values is small (compared to the number of values) but the range of the values is unknown

```
function countValuesB(values) { // example B
    const counts = new Map();
    var i,count;
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        count = counts.get(values[i]);
        if (count) { count[0]++ }
        else { counts.set(values[i], [1]) }
    }
    return counts;
}
```

### Unknown set with large range

If the set of values is large (near or greater than the length of the array) then the above example is at a disadvantage, as each new value found require that a new array is created. The new array has a higher cost than calculating the hash, so we can put the advantage to adding new items in the map of counts

#### Example C

When the set of values is large or the range is unknown

```
function countValuesC(values) {  // example C
    const counts = new Map();
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        const num = values[i];
        if (counts.has(num)) { counts.set(num, counts.get(num) + 1) }
        else { counts.set(num, 1) }
    }
    return counts;
}
```

### Bench-marking

To get a flavor as to how each performs we must benchmark the performance for different types of data. To define the data I have used the following

```
const data = (length, min, max) => setOf(length, () => randI(min, max));
```

Where `setOf` creates an array of `length`. The array contains random integers from `min` to `max-1`

If we benchmark the three example A,B,C. The values are linear metrics denoting time taken, with lower values faster.

#### Performance comparisons

```
  length |  min  |   max  ||   A   |   B   |    C   |  ~ perf Best Worst            
 -------------------------  ---------------------------------------------
  32000  |     0 |   1000 || 0.205 | 1.472 |  2.159 | A 10 times faster C
  32000  | 10000 |  11000 || 2.091 | 1.554 |  2.249 | B 30% faster C
  32000  | 10000 |1000000 || 8.888 | 4.541 |  4.003 | C 2 times faster A
```

*<sub>**Note** Function A uses max as its second argument.</sub>*

From the best of the worst (last line C) to the best of the best (first line A) processing 32000 items can have a performance difference of 2000% simply by taking advantage of the type, distribution, and range of the items being processed.

### Ternary

In JavaScript ternary expression always tend to be slightly quicker than statements. In my view ternaries are easier to read.

The two examples B,and C can be written with ternary and give both function a 3% performance increase. The benefit is marginal, but it is good practice to favor a performant and readable style over any other.

#### Example B ternary

```
function countValuesBT(values) {
    const counts = new Map();
    var i, c;
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        (c = counts.get(values[i])) ? c[0]++ : counts.set(values[i], [1]);
    }
    return counts;
}
```

#### Example C ternary

```
function countValuesCT(values) { 
    const counts = new Map();
    var i, num;
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        counts.has(num = values[i]) ?
            counts.set(num, counts.get(num) + 1) :
            counts.set(num, 1);
    }
    return counts;
}
```

Comment: My god, this is a comprehensive answer! Looking through it all now. :)

Comment: Don't these all return objects though? I needed one to return a simple array like `1,2,2,1,1' because it's easy to sort. I searched but couldn't find any way to sort an object unless the keys were the same. The keys here would all be different since it's counting each different type.

Comment: @Hasen Info on Map https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map